# Excel Criteria Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Please Help, what will I put in the grand total revenue?

There's no problem in operation but when I copy the formula and change the last criteria to "Revenue" it retuns 0 value.

I think this is because of the first criteria, it reads the blank under the Subtotal item. Anyone knows what should I do?

Kindly see the image below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Either you have to make the ranges absolute in the formula or copy/paste the formula's text in order for them not to move when you copy it (see this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/how-to-stop-excel-from-changing-a-range-when-you-drag-a-formula-down).     Also check if revenue has an extra space at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think it is only because of the first criteria. When I sort the Operation and Revenue in descending order, and change the last criteria to "Revenue", it  shows the right value for revenue and then the problem goes to Operation. They can't read the blank row of subtotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtotal is not in the same row as revenue. You can right click the "subtotal" item in the pivot table | Field settings | Layout and print | and check Repeat item labels

Comment: Thank you so much. But the "Repeat item labels" is grayed out. Is it because my file is .xls and it is not compatible? Is there any other solution aside from changing the file?

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/628707-pivot-table-will-not-repeat-row-labels.html

Comment: Also: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-item-labels-in-a-pivottable-882bdb55-9cdc-4d8d-b531-8e96e41dea31?ocmsassetID=HA101821017&CorrelationId=722a9585-6bf8-41a6-b165-1233ac9d81bc&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: But May I know if there's any other way to get the grand total in that format without repeating item label? It will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to put the cell after Subtotal label in criteria? Thank you sir.

Comment: You can look for power pivot and data model solutions. If this one helped, please mark the answer.